# Javascript skip double pipes in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
var test = "test|2014-07-22 12:13:47||ASD|\|nameOfSomething123\||anothersmt";
var s = test.split('|');
console.log(s);

//outputs
[ 'test',
  '2014-07-22 12:13:47',
  '',
  'ASD',
  '',
  'nameOfSomething123',
  '',
  'anothersmt' ]
```

Because the |nameOfSomething123| also has pipes, the split('|'), the result is not good, I need to get rid of the 5 and 6th position. No good.

I would like to split it, but skipping \|nameOfSomething123\|

Does anyone know how to solve it ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Why does one value contain the same symbol you are using for separation? That's most likely the initial problem to solve here.

Comment: I would suggest using another symbol. Much easier.

Answer (score 5):

First, I'm going to assume that your `test` string actually contains `\|` sequences. If you were to  write the string literal as you've shown, `\|` would be interpreted as an escape sequence for `|`. For this script to work as you've shown, you'd need to write `test` like this:

```
var test = "test|2014-07-22 12:13:47||ASD|\\|nameOfSomething123\\||anothersmt";
```

You can accomplish this pretty easily using [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
test.match(/(\\\||[^|])+/g);

// outputs
[ "test", 
  "2014-07-22 12:13:47", 
  "ASD", 
  "\|nameOfSomething123\|", 
  "anothersmt" ]
```

This pattern matches one or more sequences of either `\|` or any character other than `|`. Note that the the `\` and the `|` need to be escaped to refer to literal `\` and `|` characters. Given your sample input, this should accomplish the goal. (Of course if the `\` can be escaped, too, that's complicates it a bit)

If you need to capture empty strings between two pipes like `||`, then you can use `split` around the matched values and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the separators. For example:

```
test.split(/((?:\\\||[^|])*)/g).filter(function(x, i) { return i % 2 });

// outputs
[ "test", 
  "2014-07-22 12:13:47", 
  "",
  "ASD", 
  "\|nameOfSomething123\|", 
  "anothersmt" ]
```

This works because `split` will return any captured substrings as a separate entry in the result array. Then `filter` just picks every other element from the result. Note that `filter` requires ECMAScript 5.1 or later, so it may not work in older browsers. If this is a problem, see the polyfill option described in the linked documentation.

Comment: The OP should clarify, but there doesn't seem to be a request to remove the empty result before 'ASD'.

Comment: @PatrickQ Good point. I've included an alternative solution for that case.

Comment: Hi p.s.w.g. 
Thank you very much for your kind answer and for your time spent trying to help, I very much appreciate that.

Your answer is really good, except by the fact that I can't control the string that comes as this is a third party system I have no influence on. Therefore the pipes are escaped only with one back-slash by implementation, the consequence is that your regEx does not work as you have tested with two back-slashes.

Comment: @user3865142 My point was that when used in a string literal, `'\|'` evaluates to `'|'`. You can confirm this for yourself by typing `"foo\|bar" == "foo|bar"` in the console. To really test this with a string literal you have to escape the backslashes as well. `\\|` evaluates to `\|` inside a string literal. Please read [**MDN: Escaping characters**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Escaping_characters)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this is a hard problem. If your separator is *always* `|`, then the only case when you get an empty string from `.split` is going to be when you have a double `|` (or triple or quadruple). As long as the double pipes have no semantic purpose for you, all you need to do is get rid of the empty strings:

```
function check_for_empty_string(element){
    if (element.length != 0) return element;
}

s = s.filter(check_for_empty_string);
```

Now `s` should only contain non-empty strings and you're done. `Array.filter` is a javascript built-in that takes a callback that checks an element. Whatever you return from the callback passes through the filter and into the new array. Here I've used the old array as the target, for brevity, but `.filter` returns a new array so you can keep the old one if you want.

Comment: you're missing the point which is to identify escaped pipes `\|` (in your defense, the title of the post is confusing).

Comment: @Christophe fair enough, I'll resolve it once I can.

Comment: Seeing as p.s.w.g's answer pretty much fulfills the OP's needs, I don't think there's a way to amend my answer without making it identical to his. So I'll leave it here, in case someone finds this question and is looking for this solution rather than the one the OP wanted.

Comment: Double pipes has semantics, so unfortunately I can't just get rid of them :(

Comment: Well doesn't p.s.w.g's answer solve the problem? it seems to me it elegantly produces the exact output you need. You should accept it as the answer. I even upvoted it lol :P